# Please explain Kalpa theory and calculations?

Tags: yuga

- How are Kalpas traditionally calculated?
- [Sri Yukteswar Giri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukteswar_Giri) has said in [The Holy Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukteswar_Giri#The_Holy_Science) that the sun revolves around another star, [taking 24,000 years per revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuga#Sri_Yukteswar.27s_teachings_on_the_yugas). As the Sun (and our solar system) swing around the other star, our system is brought close to Vishnunabhi, the seat of creative power, Brahma. He stated that this is the age of Dharma, where humans are most spritual, honest and just etc. The opposite, i.e our solar system is as far away from Vishnunabhi as possible, is where humans are the most wicked etc.

  **Which version is correct?**  Can anyone explain and elaborate more on these?
- Are there any matches with scientific research?

For reference, [Yugas are already discussed here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2220/what-is-the-duration-timeline-of-the-four-yugas/)

Answer (score 5):

I think, I know what article you are referring to..

"the sun, with its planets and their moons, takes some star for its dual and revolves around it in about 24,000 years of our earth-a celestial phenomenon which causes the backward movement of the equinoctial points around the zodiac". - http://baharna.com/karma/yuga.htm

In science, this is called axial precession or the Precession of the Equinox. The precession of the equinox can be explained easily as follows.

Imagine earth to a top (spinning top). When the top slows down, you must have seen that it spins and starts drawing an imaginary circle around its axis. Earth rotates like that, as of today around its axis. But this imaginary circle that the earths axis is drawing in the sky actually takes around 24000 to 26000 years to complete one circle. That is called precession of the equinox.

[image: Axial Precession]
(image from wikipedia)

Also earth, the sun and solar system also is moving around the Milky way itself. This giant revolution around the center of the Milky Way takes approximately 225 to 250 million terrestrial years. - This is called the Galactic year. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_year).

Now, going back the Precession of the Equinox, the imaginary line that the Earth draws on the sky apparently traverses the zodiacal positions of the stars - The 12 zodiacs, and roughly it means that the each zodiac ranges for around 2000 - 2100 years. And the world and society experience that zodiac for that period. Somewhere in the region of 300 BC, Earth entered into Age of Pisces, and then somewhere now 2000 A.D to 2100 A.D, earth will enter into the Age of Aquarius ( The zodiac traverses in reverse, not forwards. After Aquarius, somewhere in the range of 4200 A.D , we will traverse into Age of Capricorn and so on.

You are vaguely right, in the sense that the value systems that exist during each age reflects the behavior of that zodiac. Some very impressive explanations are given for each zodiacal age in the Wiki. Take your time to go through them. But it does not indicate that value systems become corrupt.

Comment: Thanks for this impressive answer! I added an image from wikipedia that helps to clarify your top spinning example. So these are Yukteswar's Kalpas right? Would you be able to shed light on the traditional Kalpas that span millions of years?

Answer (score 3):

I have lengths of yugas and kalpas according to दाते पंचांग.

```
Kali yuga - 432000
Dwapar yuga - 864000
Treta yuga - 1296000
Sat yuga - 1728000
=Chaturyuga - 4320000

Kalp = 71*chaturyuga
Brahma's 1day = 14*manu/kalp
```

Same is for night. Brahmas life can be calculated b multiplying above figure by `30(days)*12(month)*100(years)`.

Currently Brahma's 50 years have passed. First day 7<sup>th</sup> manvantar 28<sup>th</sup> kaliyuga and year 5116 is going on.