# Who is Samvartsara, the deity of Mathematics?

Tags: identification-request, deity, mathematics

Some times ago, In [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20924/is-there-any-god-deity-for-the-mathematics), i have learned that Prajapati made Samvartsara as the lord of mathemathics.

I'm want to know about this deity, so my question is, Who is Samvartsara and What is his story? Is any Mantras/hymns for invoke this deity?

Comment: Saṁvatsara means 'year' literally, it's a unit of time measurment like ṛtu, muhūrta, pakṣa, māsa, etc. Śiva is also known by the name Saṁvatsara, but it's not like Saṁvatsara is some distinct devatā. A 'year' is *lord* of seasons, months, weeks, etc., that is how the linked śloka must be understood, according to me.