# A question about kāla

Tags: philosophy, sanskrit, creation, science, cosmology

kāla is a sanskrit Homonym word with two completely different meanings, one being time (concept of time) another one being anything related to black color, black, dark, darkness.

I was recently watching a Sadhguru video in which he spoke about in Hindu philosophy, both space as matter, darkness & time as darkness.

Meanwhile it seems modern scientists recently correlated/ concluded that both space, time & dark matter, energy are closely related. https://www.sciencealert.com/physicists-just-found-a-link-between-dark-energy-and-the-arrow-of-time

How did kāla became to be word for both time & black/dark/darkness?

Comment: This is a good question but just not the right forum. Better suited for a  linguistic or history site

Comment: Just wondering what makes you think that it's not a right forum ? @PratikBhat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who is kaal? What is kaal?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8629/who-is-kaal-what-is-kaal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Kala in context of time:**

Fact is whatever we do and however we do, we need to understand one basic thing that time does not stops for anyone nor can anyone stop time. Even if we are not doing anything time is ticking on and it has been ticking on since infinity and it will keep on doing that till infinity.

**Kala in context of darkness:**

Another fact is that everything around us is dark indeed and it has been like that since infinity and will continue to be like that for infinity. We see an object only when that object stops the light that we are getting from the sun otherwise it's all dark. But still we see just one side that side which is visible to our eyes. For instance we see moon only because it stops the light coming from sun otherwise it is a dark object but again we see only one bright side the other side is dark, on specific days we see no moon at all. But eventually sun will also become a black hole.

In Hinduism we term both time and darkness as Shiva and refer to him by many names and one of them is 'Mahakaal'

**Who is Shiva?**

Although Lord Shiva is more populary known as Mahakaal as his consort is Mahakali. 'Kala' name which means 'who is time' is stated in Taittariya Aranyaka 10.18.1

As described by Sadhguru himself [here](http://isha.sadhguru.org/mahashivratri/shiva-adiyogi/who-is-shiva-meaning/):

> Shiva is described as a non-being, not as a being. Shiva is not
>   described as light, but as darkness. Humanity has gone about
>   eulogizing light only because of the nature of the visual apparatus
>   that they carry. Otherwise, the only thing that is always, is
>   darkness. Light is a limited happening in the sense that any source of
>   light – whether a light bulb or the sun – will eventually lose its
>   ability to give out light. Light is not eternal. It is always a
>   limited possibility because it happens and it ends. Darkness is a much
>   bigger possibility than light. Nothing needs to burn, it is always –
>   it is eternal. Darkness is everywhere. It is the only thing that is
>   all pervading.