# Do the scriptures say anything about the very rapid abnormal changes happening right now?

Tags: vedas, scripture, puranas, upanishads

So called Western Industrial Revolution happened only 200 years ago as compared to millions of years of human existence on earth. The period of 200 years is extremely short in front of duration of human existence on earth. Moreover the digital technology came into being only since 50 years. Everything, be it our way of life, thinking, impact on nature and environment, etc. has happened at an extremely rapid abnormal pace in just these few years as compared to millions of years of human existence. Do the scriptures say anything about such rapid abnormal changes?

Edit: This question is not a duplicate of [In any scripture, are there any records of climate change? Example with Solutions?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/in-any-scripture-are-there-any-records-of-climate-change-example-with-solution) since that question mentions only about Climate changes, whereas the changes that I'm referring to are all sorts of changes like technological changes, psychological changes, etc.

Comment: Sri Yukteswar Giri talked about these changes in his book 'The Holy Science' written in 1894. He says we are living in ascending Dwapara Yuga and not Kali Yuga which most people believe. He said these changes started happening after 1699 which is true. See my answer [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9965/3872)

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria if this is ascending Dwapara Yuga, why is adharma spreading more and more? Why people are becoming more materialistic then as time is passing by?

Comment: Well adharma in Kali Yuga was more than what it is today. In those years, there were a lot of wars between kingdoms, people used to live like slaves. Of course, in those times also great people were born like Chandragupta Maurya and spiritual giants like Adi Shankaracharya. Let's go back 1000 years in time, it was the time of Mughal rule, compare that with today, we're much happier. Mughal rule was one of the worst periods in the history of India and it happened in Kali Yuga. But with the end of Kali Yuga in 1699, Mughal empire started to decline and more positive things started to happen.

Comment: @User5155835 Please check the following link . It might  have the answers your are looking at :)         https://vedanet.com/2012/06/13/secrets-of-the-yugas-or-world-ages/

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria You didn't say anything about why materialism is increasing more and more? Also people are becoming self centric, shrewd. People now consider their 'Body' as themselves and that they live only once, and that money is measure of success, and like to live more in divided family and not care of parents. These are serious no no from our vedic point of view. How can you explain that?

Comment: Materialism is increasing but so is spiritual light in the hearts of people. Earlier also, people were self centric, they considered body as themselves and believed they live only once. Hardly anyone followed vedic life. But atleast in today's Dwapara Yuga more and more people are interested in spiritual matters. Remember, this is ascending cycle so conditions will only improve.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria I don't think spirituality is increasing among people. From what I'm seeing as time is passing by, spirituality among people is decreasing. Also, if materialism is increasing, that means spirituality is decreasing.

Comment: Then why spirituality is increasing in you? Do you think if you were born in Kali Yuga then you would be interested in spiritual matters like you are now? Certainly not.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Its not about me. I'm saying that the amount of people interested in spirituality as compared to huge rising population is very less.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria How do you describe women nowadays not being loyal to their husbands, nor the husbands being loyal to their women, rising percentage of divorces, women smoking and drinking alcohol, ashamed of wearing sadi? These things were not there in the previous age. It means we've come from good to bad, we've not come from bad to good.

Comment: One being not loyal to another or vice versa is not the standard. Not everyone is like that. What sadi has to do with all this? You can wear whatever you want, that has nothing to do with yugas. In Kali Yuga, there was no freedom, only the king and his family were the masters, all others were slaves. There was no life for people. Work all day and get meagre wages, that's all was there in Kali Yuga. Comparing that to today, we've definitely come from bad to good.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria you need to see this link: https://grahamhancock.com/dmisrab6/ It also takes into account Sri Yukteshwar's theory

Comment: That article actually agrees with 24,000 years yuga cycle. Its only the starting and ending point of the previous yugas that separates Sri Yukteswar theory and that theory. That theory says Kali Yuga will end after a few hundred years. Sri Yukteswar came to this theory after studying the astronomical positions and the grand center called Vishnu Naabhi. The article you mentioned doesn't take Vishnu Naabhi in account so it missed an extremely important point and that is the reason why that theory is a little bit off Sri Yukteswar's thoery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In any scripture, are there any records of climate change? Example with Solutions?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/in-any-scripture-are-there-any-records-of-climate-change-example-with-solution)

Comment: @Pandya I've edited the question. This question is not a duplicate of the other question since that question mentions only about Climate changes, whereas the changes that I'm referring to are all sorts of changes like technological changes, psychological changes, etc.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar that article kind of opposes the traditional Hindu standpoint on the length of yugas, which are (in my opinion) typical signs of western ignorance.

Comment: @GabeHiemstra Which are the signs of western ignorance?

Comment: @moonstar2001 This: First showing a popup "learn with dr david drawley, $50 discount" (calling himself a vedic teacher of the modern world), then dismissing traditional Hindu standpoint on Yugas by arguing that "this view is a speculation of medieval thinkers and has several problems" and also "its accuracy is questionable". Maybe I should have called it western hypocrisy. Or both. Anyway I'd rather learn for free the opinion of someone not as biased :)

Comment: @GabeHiemstra  :-) I am surprised though since David Frawley has consistently lauded Hinduism and its tenets and speaks to its esoteric nature and yogic import (ref: his twitter a/c).