# In any scripture, are there any records of climate change? Example with Solutions?

Tags: scripture

In any scripture, are there any records of climate change? Example with Solutions?

Energy always transforms from one to another. I am looking for such examples where energy has been transformed or stored. Looking for current situations where can we store energy except Rudraksha and idols? I am looking for new form of energy such as birth of Mars and saturn, whose birth not only restored positivity but also gave a new types of planets.

Comment: "Climate change" is a modern phenomena and I think people may tend to close this question due to its nature of "scientific speculations". On an interesting note, IMO Sanjaya foresaw certain effects upon fall of Duryodhana (may be Kali demon left his body & merged within the world). It's described here in [Shalya Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m09/m09058.htm). `O king, when thy son fell. Lakes and wells, O best of kings, vomited forth blood. Rivers of rapid currents flowed in opposite directions. Women seemed to look like men, and men to look like women.`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking in the 2nd paragraph. Maybe you want to delete it, since you already accepted the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**There are  records of events happening (similar to events happen in  climate change situation ) stated  in Shreemad Bhagvatam.** After Shree Krishna's departure to Dwaraka and Arjuna going to Dwaraka to meet Shri Krishna.

> कालस्य च गतिं रौद्राम विपर्यस्ततृधार्मिण:
>  ददर्श घोररूपाणि
> निमित्तानि कुरुद्वह:।।3।।
>
> Kaalasya Cha Gatim Raudram ViparyastaturDhamirna  Paapiyasi
> Ghorarupani Nimittani Kurudwaha.
>
> Meaning - They (Yudhisthira) saw , **the time changing very
> dramatically & getting being fierce. Seasons changed  and sesons
> outcome (heat , cold)  also got reverse**.People became greedy ,
> high-tempered , and untruthful.People living by adharma.
>
> [**SB Canto 1 Adhaya 14 shloka 3**](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/14/3)

In **Sreemad Bhagavatam**,there are also elaborate descriptions & predictions of climate changes that are going to happen in the "Kaliyuga" . Like **uncertainty of rains , extreme weather conditions , cyclones , effect on grain size  , thunder stricking and above all Global warming.**

> अनावृष्टया विंगड़गक्षंति **दुर्भिक्ष**करपीड़िता: 
>  
> **शीतवातातप्रपावृंगड़हिमैरन्योन्यत**: प्रजा ।।10।।
>
> **Meaning**- Sometimes there will be heavy droughts and sometimes  heavy rain.Sometimes heavy snowfall and cold will be
> there.Cyclones will appear , heat will rise  ,there will be
> floods , people will vanish from wars afterwards.
>
> [**SB  Canto 12 Adhaya 2 Verse 10**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/2/10)
>
> अणुपरायास्वयोषधीषु शमीप्रयेषु स्थास्नुषु ।  
>  
> **विद्युत्प्रायेषु** मेघेषु शुन्यप्रायेषु सद्मसु ॥15॥
>
> **Meaning** - The grain and grain crops will become shorter.The big and
> tall  trees will became short in length & width.There will only be
> be thunder in clouds and less rain.
>
> [**SB Canto 12 Adhaya 2 Verse 15**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/2/12-16)
>
> नित्यमुद्वीग्नमनसो दुर्भिक्षकरकर्शीता:।  
>  
> **निरन्ने** भूतले राजन्ननावृष्टिभयातुरा: ।। 39।।
>
> **Meaning** -  O Rajan due to the taxes & drought people will suffer much.People will be in the state of depression due to fear of
> drought and uncertainty of rains.
>
> [**SB  Canto 12 Adahya 3 Verse 39**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/3/39-40)

These shlokas give us clear evidence about prediction and **Record** of  "Climate change" &"Global warmimg" and their effects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49046/discussion-between-yogi-and-swiftpushkar).

Comment: I agree, good answer :)